# Manipulation of InterpolatingFunction

Tags: differential-equations, function-construction

Suppose that $q[t]$ is obtained by `NDSolve` as an `InterpolatingFunction`, and I want to define $Q[t]$ to be some function of $q[t]$, say $\sqrt{q[t]}$. How can I define it in such a way that I become able to plot its time derivative for example?

Comment: If `ifun` is your interpolating function, you could for example write `Sqrt[ifun[#]] &@t` to get `Q[t]` and `Sqrt[ifun[#]] &'@t` to get `Q'[t]`.

Comment: Have a look at the package [`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolvePackages.html). It has functions to extract datapoints from an `InterpolatingFunction` object.

Comment: If I understood your new question, I believe you'll be better off in using `G[p,Q]` as a function of unevaluated `p` and `Q`, compute its partial derivatives wrt `p` and `Q` and only then substitute the `InterpolatingFunction`s for their values.

Comment: @Peltio The problem is that if I do that, even without taking the partial derivative, I can't take the time derivative as I can for `G[p[t], Q[t]]`.

Comment: Should I transfer the edit into a separate question?

Comment: I think it would be better, because it's a different question. But as far as I understood it, you have to choose how to express your function (as a function of t like in f[x[t],y[t]] to compute the derivative with respect to t, or as a function of x,y like in f[x,y], to compute the derivatives with respect to x and y). You can't have both at the same time. A separate question, possibly with an example of intended behavior, can clarify what you really need to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I might be grossly mistaken, but what is preventing you to compute a function of an interpolating function?

```
 NDSolve[{x''[t] + .2x'[t] + x[t] == 0, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == .4}, x[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

> ```
>    InterpolatingFunction[{{0,10}},<>][t]
> ```

Define your function in this way

```
f[t_] = x[t] /. %[[1]];
```

Then you can compute functions of it, like it was another function

```
g[t_] = Sqrt[f[t]]
```

> ```
>    Sqrt[ InterpolatingFunction[{{0,10}},<>][t] ]
> ```

Computing the derivative is using the composition rule

```
g'[t]
```

> ```
>    InterpolatingFunction[{{0,10}},<>][t]/(2 Sqrt[InterpolatingFunction[{{0,10}},<>][t])
> ```

and like other functions you might have warnings when you try to plot imaginary values... So might be forced to use `Abs` or `Re` or `Im`.

```
Plot[{Abs[g[t]], Abs[g'[t]]}, {t, 0, 10}, Frame -> True]
```

Comment: Hmmmmm... this is embarrassing :) Who would have thought of this...

Comment: A long time ago, in a galaxy far, far away, Mathematica developers used to write articulated... articles in The Mathematica Journal about the new features introduced with new versions. But that was, as I've said, a long time ago. These days there is much less... articulation :-). Anyway, your approach shows an easy way to extract data points from interpolating functions. The OP will certainly appreciate it.

Comment: @Peltio Thanks Peltio. Please note the edit in the question.

Answer (score 6):

```
Needs@"DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`";

if = y /. First@NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}]

dataY = InterpolatingFunctionValuesOnGrid@if;
dataX = Flatten@InterpolatingFunctionGrid@if;

{
 ListPlot@Transpose@{dataX, dataY},
 ListPlot@Transpose@{dataX, dataY^3}
 }
```

> ```
>  InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 30.}}, <>]
> ```
>
> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I have never hear about `InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy` +1! However there is simpler method: `if["Coordinates"]` and `if["ValuesOnGrid"]` make the job. A list of all possible options: `PropertyList[if]`.